# Can't pip a certain setup.py

Tags: python, ssl, pip

So I'm trying to install [this python script](https://github.com/drdrang/python-itunes), which is required to run [this workflow](https://github.com/drdrang/isearch). It's been a while since I used the Terminal or python. I think something has gone awry.

I think there are two errors here, one is about SSL, the second is about what pip is trying to do and why it's failing. I just can't interpret what is thrown at up.

```
> user$ sudo -H pip install Dropbox/Developer/AppleScripts/iTunesaff/python-itunes/setup.py
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 268, in run
    wheel_cache
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 268, in populate_requirement_set
    wheel_cache=wheel_cache
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 207, in from_line
    wheel_cache=wheel_cache)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 66, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2960, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2904, in parse_requirements
    "version spec")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2869, in scan_list
    raise ValueError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'Dropbox/Developer/AppleScripts/iTunesaff/python-itunes/setup.py', 'at', '/Developer/AppleScripts/iTunesaff/python-itunes/setup.py')
```

Comment: You probably want `python setup.py install` instead `pip install`

Comment: Or you can use pip but give it the path of the directory containing the setup.py file and not the actual path of the setup.py file.

Comment: Thank you both. It was a package so pip to path of directory worked well!